# Attaching different LibreOffice Writer documents

Tags: libreoffice

I have a lot of .odt documents. How can I attach them  together without hurting their contents?

Copy and paste in LibreOffice is not safe and may [change the format](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/30970/copy-paste-problem-in-writer/). For example, the position of sliders for lines may be forgotten.

Comment: If you mean into one document, LibreOffice calls that a "master document". If you just want into one file, `tar` or `zip`? Please clarify which you mean.

Comment: into one document‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibreOffice calls one document made up of many sub-documents a "master document".

1. File -> New -> Master Document. You have to use the menu; it's not in the splash screen.
2. In the Navigator that pops up, click the Insert icon, the select "File"
3. Select your files. You may select multiple files using Shift-click or Control-click.
4. Press insert.
5. Repeat the "Insert" step as many times as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the tool [OOoPy](http://ooopy.sourceforge.net/). One of the tools included with this toolset is called `ooo_cat` which does what you want.

> ooo_cat for concatenating several OOo files into one

#### Installation

After downloading it you can install the tool set like so:

```
$ python setup.py install
```

After which `ooo_cat` will show up on your `$PATH`. Usage is pretty straightforward:

```
$ ooo_cat --help
```

Usage: ooo_cat [-o|--output-file ] [file, ...]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o OUTPUT_FILE, --output-file=OUTPUT_FILE
                        Output file (defaults to stdout)

#### Example

Say I have this fake document named `out2.odt`. I can concatenate it as many times as I want like so:

```
$ ooo_cat -o new.odt out2.odt out2.odt
```

The resulting `new.odt`:

```
$ ls -l new.odt out2.odt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 10061 Apr  7 21:52 new.odt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml  9816 Apr  7 21:40 out2.odt
```

Now when we open it up:

```
$ ooffice new.odt
```

[image: ss of new doc]

**NOTE:** There are 2 copies of `out2.odt` in `new.odt` now. Above is showing the 2 pages side by side for reference.