# Converting .odm to .odt

Tags: libreoffice

How can I convert LibreOffice Master Document which consists of several .odt files into a single .odt file‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of any of the open document formats are simply ZIP files, so one could use `unzip` to unpack their contents.

#### To see the contents

```
$ unzip -l MasterDocumentTemplateDR.odm 
Archive:  MasterDocumentTemplateDR.odm
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       46  02-04-2012 22:16   mimetype
      111  02-04-2012 22:16   Pictures/100002000000000C0000000CC1B54C41.gif
       97  02-04-2012 22:16   Pictures/100002000000000A0000000AD0B8BA86.gif
    10389  02-04-2012 22:16   Pictures/100000000000028F000001ED1B3CF428.jpg
    13036  02-04-2012 22:16   Pictures/10000201000000960000005E2C8645FE.png
      103  02-04-2012 22:16   Pictures/100002000000000A0000000A1F4FBE6C.gif
     1438  02-04-2012 22:16   meta.xml
     9005  02-04-2012 22:16   settings.xml
    48009  02-04-2012 22:16   content.xml
    10830  02-04-2012 22:16   Thumbnails/thumbnail.png
      427  02-04-2012 22:16   layout-cache
      899  02-04-2012 22:16   manifest.rdf
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/popupmenu/
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/images/Bitmaps/
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/toolpanel/
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/statusbar/
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/toolbar/
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/progressbar/
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/menubar/
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/floater/
        0  02-04-2012 22:16   Configurations2/accelerator/current.xml
   155673  02-04-2012 22:16   styles.xml
     1808  02-04-2012 22:16   META-INF/manifest.xml
---------                     -------
   251871                     23 files
```

#### To unzip the contents

```
$ unzip MasterDocumentTemplateDR.odm

$ ls -l
total 248
drwxrwxr-x. 11 saml saml   4096 Jul 11 16:23 Configurations2
-rw-rw-r--.  1 saml saml  48009 Feb  4  2012 content.xml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 saml saml    427 Feb  4  2012 layout-cache
-rw-rw-r--.  1 saml saml    899 Feb  4  2012 manifest.rdf
drwxrwxr-x.  2 saml saml   4096 Jul 11 16:23 META-INF
-rw-rw-r--.  1 saml saml   1438 Feb  4  2012 meta.xml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 saml saml     46 Feb  4  2012 mimetype
drwxrwxr-x.  2 saml saml   4096 Jul 11 16:23 Pictures
-rw-rw-r--.  1 saml saml   9005 Feb  4  2012 settings.xml
-rw-rw-r--.  1 saml saml 155673 Feb  4  2012 styles.xml
drwxrwxr-x.  2 saml saml   4096 Jul 11 16:23 Thumbnails
```

#### Converting a ODM to ODT file

If you go under the "File" menu there's a menu item called "Export". Selecting this will bring up the following dialog, from where you can "export" your `.odm` file to the `.odt` file format.

[image: ss #1]

[image: ss #2]

Which will result in a `.odt` file being produced.

```
$ ls -l
total 136
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 59383 Feb  4  2012 MasterDocumentTemplateDR.odm
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 52176 Jul 11 16:54 MasterDocumentTemplateDR.odt
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - the contents of the .odm file are already split up into several .odt files. The only piece this is missing is the mashing of the .odt files into a single one. But to answer that would be highly dependent on what's in the .odt files, IMO. I need more info and for the OP to first acknowledge that they're aware of this.

Comment: I can access each individual .odt file in the .odm file. I'm looking for a method to save the .odm file as a big .odt file.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - what about anything else that's potentially inside it? Notice the example I showed, does your .odm file contain only .odt files?

Comment: I have several .odt files inserted into an empty .odm file.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - see updates.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling -  see updates.

Comment: @slm Downvote retracted.

Comment: @slm No problem - I downvoted the answer because I felt it wasn't useful in answering the question, and with your edits, it now does answer the question so a downvote has no place IMO.

Comment: Really it did not solve my problem! An odt file is created but it is readonly and still depends on previous files. The same as odm file. I want an independent odt file.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - can you give us your `.odm` file? The `.odt` file I created contains everything that was in the `.odm` file so it seems like it worked for me.

Comment: Solved. I found this: https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=71707 . In which it is explained that I have to Press F5 in the all-in-one odt file. Then I have to click edit on each sub-odt file and then uncheck both *link* and *protected* and check *editable*. btw, still the sub-odt files exist inside the all-in-one odt file and I have to no solution to remove them so that I get a normal not partitioned odt file.

Answer (score 1):

I had several .odt files. I added them in an .odm file. Then as in [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144067/62511) I exported the .odm file into an all_in_one.odt file.

the all_in_one.odt file depends on the original .odt files, if they are deleted all_in_one.odt will be empty. To solve this I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd>  then I right clicked on the original .odt file in the Navigator window and chose *Edit* and unchecked *Link* and *Protected* and checked *Editable*:
[image]

[more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123660/attaching-different-libreoffice-writer-documents)