# Converting .odm to .odt or .pdf - command line

Tags: command-line, conversion, libreoffice, openoffice

I saw this question: [Converting .odm to .odt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144054/converting-odm-to-odt), where someone shows to convert an `.odm` file into `.odt` or `.pdf`. Is there also a way to do this in a command line?

I have an Open Document Master file, which has a link to two external files, but when I type:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf master.odm
```

Then I only see a blank file. The same when I first try to convert into `odt` and then into `pdf`:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to odt master.odm
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf master.odt
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @glennjackman doesn't look OT to me. Doesn't it come under "[Applications packaged in *nix distributions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)"?